# Integration problem yields two solutions. But are they the same?

Tags: calculus

I have an integration problem: $\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt {x^{12}-1}}dx$.

My attempt was to let $u=\sqrt {x^{12}-1}$. Solving it yields:

$$\frac{1}{6}\int\frac{1}{u^2+1}du$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\tan^{-1}(u)+C$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\tan^{-1}\sqrt {x^{12}-1}+C$$

However, my TA substituted $u=\frac{1}{x}$, and subsequently $v=u^6$. Solving it yields:

$$-\frac{1}{6}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt {1-v^2}}dv$$
$$=-\frac{1}{6}\sin^{-1}(v)+C$$
$$=-\frac{1}{6}\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{x^6}+C$$

I do not understand how the two answers are different but mathematically are correct. When I tried to draw a right-angled triangle using the first solution, I would have:

opposite = $\sqrt{x^{12}-1}$

adjacent = $1$

hypotenuse = $x^6$

So from the above, $\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{x^{12}-1}}{x^6}$ and $\theta=\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{x^{12}-1}}{x^6}$, which is not the same as $-\arcsin\frac{1}{x^6}$

May I know what is wrong with my deduction above?

Note: I also tried to differentiate both solutions. The first solution will yield back to the integrand. But the second solution does not. But strangely, if I use any arbitrary limits on the two solutions, both give me the same answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try opposite = $1$, hypotenuse = $x^6$

Comment: I tried that too, but that will yield $\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt {x^{12}-1}}$ which is not $\arctan\sqrt{ x^{12}-1}$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: use $\arctan x + \arctan(1/x) = constant$

Comment: An observant TA would still mark your answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to your consideration,

$\cos\theta = \frac{1}{x^6} \Rightarrow \theta = \cos^{-1}(\frac1{x^6})$

And $\cos^{-1}x = \frac\pi2-\sin^{-1}x$.

So, $\boxed{\theta = \frac\pi2 - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)}$.

Now, $\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac\pi2$ is just a constant and you have the required result as $\boxed{- \frac16\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right) +k}$

Answer (score 0):

The graph of $\frac{1}{6}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^{12}-1}$ and $-\frac{1}{6}\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{x^6}$ looks like this:
[image]
The red line is $-\frac{1}{6}\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{x^6}$ and the other $\frac{1}{6}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^{12}-1}$. They are just the same, but what makes the difference is the $+C$ constant. This is why the constant of integration is important. Both expressions differ only by a constant.